# How to expose only few 'names' (variables/functions) in a python (importable) script

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, namespaces

I have following Python script:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3 -u
# encoding: utf-8

import zmq
import logging
import os

_zmq_channel = "ipc:///tmp/hms_logger.ipc"


class _Logger:
    _instance = None
    _instance_pid = 0

    def __init__(self):
        ctx = zmq.Context.instance()
        self._logger = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
        self._logger.connect(zmq_channel)

    @classmethod
    def instance(cls):
        if cls._instance is None or cls._instance_pid != os.getpid():
            cls._instance = cls()
            cls._instance_pid = os.getpid()
        # print(cls._instance)
        return cls._instance

    def _write(self, obj):
        self._logger.send_pyobj(obj)

    def debug(self, msg: str):
        self._write((logging.DEBUG, msg))

    def info(self, msg: str):
        self._write((logging.INFO, msg))

    def warn(self, msg: str):
        self.warning(msg)

    def warning(self, msg: str):
        self._write((logging.WARNING, msg))

    def error(self, msg: str):
        self._write((logging.ERROR, msg))

    def critical(self, msg: str):
        self._write((logging.CRITICAL, msg))


def get_logger():
    return _Logger.instance()
```

If I import above script, how can I make sure only `get_logger()` is imported and other names like `_Logger`, `_zmq_channel` are not imported, i.e. importing them should generate some error or warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this.

Basically, by default, if I import this module in some other file, using:

`import thismodule`
Or
`from thismodule import *`

The Only the names not starting with `_`(underscore) will be imported.

However, if someone deliberately imports the `_` names, they will be imported:

`from thismodule import _Logger`

Therefore, one way of partially hiding the variables/names in a python odule is to name them starting with `_`

One more way, I found was to define a special variable in the module: `__all__`

Define a variable `__all__` with value as a `list` of names you want to import.
The names must be exactly same as variable name and must be surrounded by `''` or `""`

e.g.: `__all__ = [ 'get_logger' ]`

This can be defined anywhere in your module, however, best place is to define it on the top, after imports, so that exported names are easily accessible.